# Why this is happening?

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am new to express. I am developing a MERN app and at the time of creating the server with express I faced an error.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PATH = require("path");
const LAYOUT = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 
app.use(LAYOUT);
app.set("views", PATH.join(__dirname,"/resources/views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listning on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

The error was

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory "C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\resources\views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:113:20
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:278:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\ayond\OneDrive\Desktop\my_projects\mern\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
```

but when I use the routes before the set and use methode It's working as expected. Why this is happening?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PATH = require("path");
const LAYOUT = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
  });
app.use(LAYOUT);
app.set("views", PATH.join(__dirname,"/resources/views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listning on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Comment: It's looking for a view (file) called `layout` in the `resources\views` directory.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer then why it is working when i shift routes before set and use methode

Comment: probably it is no longer in your processing chain and is being ignored

Answer (score 0):

With the windows OS, I think you should use

app.set("views", PATH.join(__dirname,"resource\views"));

instead of. Because these are the syntax of directory on window
you can check it by using
console.log(__dirname);
to know exactly the directory you are locating.